# SQL command using Psycopg2 to get hour in datetime reading

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a datetime value in a database column, and I want to get all rows that have the hour portion of the reading between 5 and 6 for example. How can I do this in python using psycopg2? Here is an example reading:

2013-10-05 00:15:31.769049

Where I would want to target the 00

I have tried using strftime, using the command

`select time from sen_reading where time.strftime("%H:") = 5;`

However, I am getting the error column "%H" does not exist

Comment: What was the problem when you tried it?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I was trying to use substring, but I was not having luck

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve tuples that have a matching hour, or are you trying to parse out the hour from the returned tuples?

Comment: @titanofold parse out the hour, right now looking at strftime in python

Comment: @titanofold updated my post to reflect my progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use the [date and time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) provided by PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT time FROM sen_reading WHERE extract(hour from time) = 5;
```

You can also create an index to speed things up a bit:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ON sen_reading (extract(hour from time));
```